# Simple bot command is not working in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to know in which text channels admin want to enable my bot functions. But in this case my code is not working.

The main idea was when admin typing `!enable` in text-chat, bot reacts to it and add text-chat id, guild id(`ctx.channel.id`) to the list, then bot responds in chat with `bot has been enabled`.

code where this command is not working:

```
channel = []
@bot.command()
async def enable(ctx):
    global channel
    print("Debug")
    await ctx.send('Restriction bot has been enabled for this text channel.')
    channel.append(ctx.channel.id)
```

full bot code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user.name}.')


channel = []
@bot.command()
async def enable(ctx):
    global channel
    print("Debug")
    await ctx.send('Restriction bot has been enabled for this text channel.')
    channel.append(ctx.channel.id)


@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == bot.user:
        return
    #if ctx.channel.id != [for channnels in channel]:
    #    return
    if ctx.attachments[0].height:
        await ctx.author.send('Your media file is restricted!')
        await ctx.delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `channel` variable is initialized in your program so each time you will restart your bot, it will be emptied. One way you can solve your problem is by storing them in a file. The easiest way to do it would be to use the json library. You'll need to create a `channels.json` file.

- The code :

```py
from json import loads, dumps

def get_data():
    with open('channels.json', 'r') as file:
        return loads(file.read())

def set_data(chan):
    with open('channels.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(dumps(chan, indent=2))

@bot.command()
async def enable(ctx):
    channels = get_data()
    channels.append(ctx.channel.id)
    set_data(channels)
    await ctx.send('Restriction bot has been enabled for this text channel.')
```

- The `channels.json` file :

```
[]
```

Comment: i recorded your code into my `bot.py` and created new `members.json` file(but you typed to create a channels.json, maybe its typo idk), i got no result. I think main error its in @bot.command()

Comment: The only thing this command is doing is adding every channels where !enable was wrote. I forgot to tell you that you needed to add an empty list in channels.json

Comment: thanks a lot! i think i need to fix my @bot.command() cuz when i type !enable there are no effect in chat :D

Comment: Do you have any error message when you type your command ?

Comment: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'loads' is not defined` this is json thing, really dont know why its arguing about. But i recently tried to build new `bot.py` test function(when i say !test bot will type `Hello!`, and its worked. Is there a limitation about @bot.command(), like 1 bot.command in 1 `.py` file? Here is my full code: https://hastebin.com/nomivasavu.py

Comment: ohhhh, I know why it isn't working xD, it's just a simple importation error. You need to replace `import json` to `from json import loads, dumps`. There's no such limitation as 1 command per file tho.

Comment: thanks, very grateful to you! its finally working, but if i try to add more than 1 text-channels he removes the last id and replaces it with a new one, i try with insert() it not worked

Comment: It's just because I'm dumb xD I forgot to replace the second `members.json` in the `set_data` function. If you copy paste the code now, it should be working (I tried it to just to make sure)